# Can I select an array from every document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

I have a collection of blogPost documents in mongodb. Each blog post has a `comments` array containing comment documents. Is it possible for me to query mongodb and get back a list of all comments combined into a single list?

[image]

I would like to build a single projection of all comments from every blog post.

Comment: Have you considered a projection returning the arrays for each post's comments as a cursor?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I'm new to mongodb so I'll be honest and say I don't really know what you mean.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#project-certain-fields-in-the-result-set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to use the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to accomplish this. Specifically, [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/).

For example:

```
db.blogPost.aggregate(
    { $project: {
        _id : 0 ,
        comments: 1 }
    },
    { $unwind: "$comments" }
);
```

Alternatively, if viable in your situation, you could just perform the concatenation of comments at the application level instead of database level, making the Mongo query simply that of over all blog posts.

Comment: If aggregation was your choice, make sure you're aware of the limitations such as the result can be no larger than 16MB. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/

Comment: Further, all results would need to be collected before any results are returned, which may be a performance issue.

Comment: Good point about the 16MB limit. Re: your other point, is that really true for `$unwind`? I thought it only applied to `$sort` and `$group`.

Comment: As far as I know, the results are returned as one BSON document (hence the 16MB limit)

Comment: The reason I wanted to do it at the db level is I was running a manual query to find all comments and order them by date. I didn't need to do that in code.